# Difference between 牛仔 ㄗˇ 褲 and 牛仔 ㄗㄞˇ 褲?

Tags: culture

It' same thing or not ?

Curious about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"仔" has three pronunciation - "zǐ","zǎi","zī". http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/2760.html

It pronounces "zǐ" when used to describe "young living beings", especially animal, such as 仔兽(野兽的幼仔); 仔猪(猪的幼仔), and used to describe the attitude that "paying attention to the tiniest/fineness detail" - 仔细(细心;详细); 仔密(致密).

It pronounces "zǎi" when used as a noun for the "young living beings". The original meaning "仔" is "little kid" (小孩), or "young animal" (羊仔;牛仔;猪仔), it has late used in the names for young persons that have a special trait or career - (肥仔;单车仔;牛仔).

Since 牛仔褲 is a "noun", so I think the correct pronunciation should be "zǎi".

Comment: NICE Answer. thanks